# angular2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefaultChangeDetectionStrategy' in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, angular

My app local works in local and used to work in production. However, I get this error on console in production.

```
main.fd49057….bundle.js:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDefaultChangeDetectionStrategy' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.fd49057….bundle.js:57)
    at r (inline.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.fd49057….bundle.js:43)
    at r (inline.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.fd49057….bundle.js:1721)
    at r (inline.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.fd49057….bundle.js:1658)
    at r (inline.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.fd49057….bundle.js:1693)
    at r (inline.js:1)
```

This is how I deploy to production on s3

```
ng build -prod
aws --profile ttt s3 sync dist/ s3://angular.bhead.com --acl public-read
```

I then deployed on firebase and it works...

Most disturbing is that it works in FF and Safari in production. I get this error in Chrome only with deployment in either s3 or Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Check your version of angular and make sure it matches all the other related libraries. I had the same issue when I added Angular 4's core library. I doesn't hold the angular core object in the same property as the previous versions. I hope that helps.